# how to choose a field value from a specific stream in storm

Tags: apache-storm

```
public void execute(Tuple input) {
 Object value = input.getValueByField(FIELD_NAME);
 ...
}
```

When calling `getValueByField`, how do I specify a particular stream name emitted by previous Bolt/Spout so that particular FIELD_NAME is coming from that stream?

I need to know this because I'm facing the following exception:

```
  InvalidTopologyException(msg:Component: [bolt2-name] subscribes from non-existent stream: [default] of component [bolt1-name])
```

So, I want to specify a particular stream while calling getValueBy... methods.

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember a way of doing it on a tuple, but you can get the information of who sent you the tuple:

```
String sourceComponent = tuple.getSourceComponent();
String streamId = tuple.getSourceStreamId();
```

Then you can use a classic switch/case in java to call a specific method that will know which fields are available.

You can also iterate through fields included in your tuple to check if the field is available but I find this way dirty.

```
for (String field : tuple.getFields()) {
     // Check something on field...
}
```

Comment: please check my answer and post your comment if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just found out that the binding to a specific stream could be done while building topology.

The `Spout` could declare fields to a stream (in `declareOutputFields` method)

```
declarer.declareStream(streamName, new Fields(field1, field2));
```

...and emit value to the stream

```
collector.emit(streamName, new Values(value1, value2...), msgID);
```

When `Bolt` is being added in the topology, it could subscribe to a specific stream from preceding spout or bolt like following

```
topologyBuilder.setBolt(boltId, new BoltClass(), parallelismLevel)
.localOrShuffleGrouping(spoutORBoltID, streamID);
```

The overloaded version of the method `localOrShuffleGrouping` provides an option to specify streamID as last argument.